# how to transform paypalipn.php from github to live?

Tags: php, paypal

So i ran all tests and went online with my app on paypal.

Payment is working good but i have a problem with converting paypalipn.php that is posted in github into the live version.

[Github paypalipn.php](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master)

[example_usage.php](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/example_usage.php)

/php/PaypalIPN.php
Which are to be changed to be able to get the LIVE ipn from paypal ?

In sandbox works fine.

Even tested that payment goes through.

Only have problem with receiving the live ipn.

In my account in paypal the IPN has been set aswell. So it's just a matter of these 2 files to be converted to live.

Comment: If you refer to the paypalipn.php, you can see that $use_sandbox = false and useSandbox is used to set this variable to true ( which will be pointing to sandbox environment ). So in the example usage, just commenting the useSandbox should be fine.

Comment: I don't understand. I tried to set it to true from false but still doesn't work. Cause it says that bool = false to use sandbox

Comment: Please can you give me an example with the code

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured out how finally !!!

in paypalipn.php 
change :

```
public function useSandbox()
 {
     $this->use_sandbox = true;
 }
```

to:

```
 public function useSandbox()
 {
     $this->use_sandbox = false;
 }
```

and in example_usage.php
change:

```
$ipn->useSandbox();
```

to:

```
//$ipn->useSandbox();
```

Hope this helps to others trying to figure this out :)

Now am LIVE xxx